# ASP.Net Core SignalR как лучше делать?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

Т.к. в Core версии клиента сигнала убрали HubProxy, то возник вопрос, собственно, как подключаться к, допустим, 5-ти хабам? Каждое подключение делать для каждого хаба? А если их будет 10? Перемещать всю логику в один хаб?

Comment: всё в один хаб, к сожалению без альтернатив. Либо мириться с тем что будет много коннектов и докупать память )

Comment: Для чего они так сделали? Что им не нравилось? Было же всё хорошо и удобно, у меня же каша будет полная, если всё в 1 хаб засунуть...

Comment: в будущем они планируют новый транспорт реализовать, который не будет иметь этого оверхеда, а сейчас вот как есть. Ответ есть на гитхабе: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/26537#issuecomment-703057243

Comment: В целом понял. Спасибо за ссылку, полазил, почитал, пишут, что лучше делать так, как сделано у меня сейчас - partial (например) класс, много методов и много сервисов, которые передаются в класс хаба, где просто идет передача данных в сервис.
Можете написать свой ответ, я его отмечу решением.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

К сожалению, в новом SignalR (Core) придется все делать через один хаб, либо мириться с тем что будет много коннектов и докупать память под избыточные коннекты.

Автор *SignalR (David Fowler)* написал что в будущем они планируют реализовать новый транспорт, который не будет иметь этого оверхеда, а сейчас вот как есть.
В идеале нужно сделать так, чтобы в будущем было просто разделить их на соответствующие хабы и когда подвезут новый транспорт перейти.
Ответ на [гитхабе](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/26537#issuecomment-703057243)